# Why doesn't this SEDE query work as expected?

Tags: support, comments, data-explorer, comment-votes

Going though [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66765/my-most-popular-comments) which displays my most popular comments, I was surprised to see just 3 comments with a score of 5 or more appear in the list.

I remember posting several comments on StackOverflow which has had a score greater than 4. I've also earned the [Pundit badge](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/94/pundit?userid=3049655) on StackOverflow which stands as a proof that I have posted more than 10 comments with a score of 5 or more.

- Why doesn't the query above work as expected?
- Is there a "working" query?
- How many comments with a score of 5 or more do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query is working just fine, it shows you the comments that *existed up until the last database copy* (it is updated once a week). So as of the last database update (earlier this morning) you have just 3 comments that have 5 votes or more.

However, the query cannot list comments on *deleted* questions nor will it list deleted comments; there may well have been more that qualified you for the badge.

Comment: @CoolGuy: right, but it won't list deleted comments. Or comments on deleted posts.

Comment: Are you sure that the Pundit badge is given for
comments posted on Meta? I've never read it anywhere before. Also, I haven't got it on MSO. I have it on SO though.

Comment: Oops, no, that's my mistake; got mixed up with another badge.